# Inverse of Non-Linear Equations - MatLab

Tags: matlab, inverse, nonlinear-functions

I have been trying without success to figure out how to invert the two equations shown below. As you can see, the equations are fairly complex nonlinear equation expressing R and T (reflection and transmission coefficients in acoustics) as a function of the variables n, k, d, and xi. What I need is to invert these equations and get expressions for xi and n in terms of the other variables. i is the imaginary unit.

Starting Equations

[image: Starting Equations]

I know the answer I need to get (second image) and I am trying to replicate this answer using some MatLab code. m is branch number of the cos inverse (arccos) function.

Solution to aim for

[image: Solution to aim for]

Comment: Do you need MATLAB to find you the true inverse, or would a numerical approximation be sufficient?

Comment: Unfortunately, a numerical approximation would not be sufficient. Finding the inverse is just one step of many I need to carry out. The goal is to later on plug in various R and T values that have been calculated to then evaluate n and xi for k ranging from 0 to about 3 (k here is actually the wavenumber obtained by diving angular frequency by the speed of sound)

Comment: I suppose I’m not sure what you need. Do you already have the forward function in MATLAB and need the inverse generated automatically, or do you just need to find out how to hand-code the inverse function?

Answer (score 1):

**1.-** Since `surf`, like `plot` and other commands, requires `X` and `Y` to be same length, graphically inverting the function, what in AutoCAD is called rotating the UCS rather that starting with a symbolic inversion attempt, makes sense.

**UCS** : **U**niversal **C**oordinates **S**ystem . The tripod on the CAD drawing sheet indicating axes and origin.

```
% MATLAB
close all;clear all;clc

c0=299792458; % [m/s] light velocity

% guessing frequency band centre

f0=2e9;                 % [Hz]
lambda0=c0/f0;      % wavelength
k0=2*pi/lambda0   % wave number

d=.03  % 3 [cm]? chip size? connector? antenna? waveguide length? the kettle?

% range_n=[0:lambda0/10:lambda0/4];
range_n=[0:.01:4.25];
range_e=[0:.05:10];
[N,E]=meshgrid(range_n,range_e);

%% Reflection Coefficient

R=1j*tan(N*k0*d).*(1./E-E)./(2-1j*tan(N*k0*d).*(1./E+E));

figure(1);
ax1=gca;
hs1=surf(ax1,N,E,abs(R))
hs1.EdgeColor='none';
grid on;xlabel('n');ylabel('e');zlabel('abs(R)');title('|R(n,e)|')
```

[image]

[image]

```
xcr1_1=ax1.XTickLabel;  % x axis x measure ruler
xcr1_2=ax1.YTickLabel;  % x axis y measure ruler

figure(2);
ax2=gca;
hs2=surf(ax2,N,E,angle(R))
hs2.EdgeColor='none';
grid on;xlabel('n');ylabel('e');zlabel('angle(R)');title('phase(R(n,e)) [rad]')
```

[image]

```
%% Transmission Coefficient

T=2./(cos(N*k0*d).*(2-1j*tan(N*k0*d).*(1./E+E)));

figure(3);
ax3=gca;
hs3=surf(ax3,N,E,abs(T))
hs3.EdgeColor='none';
grid on;xlabel('n');ylabel('e');zlabel('abs(T)');title('|T(n,e)|')
```

[image]

It makes sense that where there's high reflection then there's low transmission and where there's low reflection, then `T` gets close or equal to 1.

It's a passive device / material.

[image]

```
figure(4);
ax4=gca;
hs4=surf(ax4,N,E,angle(T))
hs4.EdgeColor='none';
grid on;xlabel('n');ylabel('e');zlabel('angle(T)');title('phase(T(n,e))')
```

[image]

**2.- Now `E` from the other side, the sought inversion :**

```
E2up=abs((((1+R).^2-T.^2)./((1-R)-T.^2)).^.5);
E2down=-abs((((1+R).^2-T.^2)./((1-R)-T.^2)).^.5);

[sz_s11,sz_s12]=size(E2up);
range_s11=[1:1:sz_s11];
range_s12=[1:1:sz_s12];

[sz_s1,sz_s2]=size(E2up);
range_s11=[1:1:sz_s11];
range_s12=[1:1:sz_s12];

[S11,S12]=meshgrid(range_s11,range_s12);

% |E(S,T)|>0

figure(5);
ax5=gca;
hs5=surf(ax5,S11,S12,abs(E2up'));
hs5.EdgeColor='none';
grid on;xlabel('s1_R');ylabel('s1_T');zlabel('abs(E_u_p)');title('|E_u_p(s1_R,s1_T)|')
```

[image]

`s1_R` `s1_T` variables in this particular context **ARE NOT** scattering parameters.

`s1_r` `s1_T` are numerals, indexs related to `R` and `T`.
`n` and `m` already in use.

**3.- Changing** inverted surface `X` `Y` **numerals to `R` `T`**

```
ax5.XTickLabel=xcr1_1;  % x axis x change ruler
ax5.YTickLabel=xcr1_2;  % x axis y change ruler
xlabel(ax5,'R');ylabel(ax5,'T');zlabel(ax5,'|(E_u_p)| positive values only');
```

[image]

```
% |E(S,T)|<0

ax6=gca;
hs6=surf(ax6,S11,S12,abs(E2down'));
hs6.EdgeColor='none';
grid on;xlabel('s1_R');ylabel('s1_T');zlabel('abs(E2_d_o_w_n)');title('|E_d_o_w_n(s1_R,s2_T)|')

ax6.XTickLabel=xcr1_1;  % x axis x change ruler
ax6.YTickLabel=xcr1_2;  % x axis y change ruler
xlabel(ax6,'R');ylabel(ax6,'T');zlabel(ax6,'|(E_d_o_w_n)| negative values only');
```

[image]

**4.- Comments :**

**4.1.-** Repeat for `angle(Edown(R,T))` and then for `n_up(R,T)` `n_down(R,T)`.

**4.2.-** Including the `2*pi*m/(k0*d)` shouldn't be difficult either.

**4.3.-** Assumed waveguide filled with air.

Dielectrics modify `lambda0` to `lambda` `k0` to `k` and may add more cut-offs.

**4.4.-** Is the material **homogeneous** and **isotropic**?